# AppCompat v21, MenuInflater and showAsAction menu preference

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-menu, android-appcompat

I'm migrating my app to the newest v7 Support Library with material design support.

I've a simple menu that I want to show in my `ActionBar`.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/platformselect_button_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
</menu>
```

The problem is that the showAsAction preference is ignored, what I have to do to make it work is force the preference in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.platformselect_overflow_menu, menu);
    for(int i = 0;i<menu.size();i++){
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menu.getItem(i), MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why is the preference stored in XML ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a different namespace when using AppCompat.

Try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/platformselect_button_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
</menu>
```

From the docs here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

> **Using XML attributes from the support library** 
>   Notice that the
>   showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the
>    tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by
>   the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the
>   Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace
>   as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

Comment: Adding the app namespace gives me this error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'res-auto'

Comment: Then something else is wrong with your project. My answer is correct. See docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

Comment: Using yourapp instead of app everything works properly. Maybe app is a reserved name for namespaces?

Comment: "app" works fine for me. Possibly a conflict with another namespace you have?

Comment: No, app works for me too. I did a copy-paste of namespace right from the article, the problem is in your answer: namespace should be `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` without the `/res` preceding `/res-auto`. I didn't notice before.

Comment: Sorry. Typo there. Corrected answer.

Comment: But why did it work with sherlock in the android: namespace? Then it did not exist on the old devices as well